# Label not displaying as expected with select box

Tags: html, css

I am tired of searching for the solution all day but can't find why my label is not working.
When I write only HTML then it works but as soon I applied CSS in it, it stopped working.
Talking about "Section Start" label it should be linked with "selectbox".Other labels work fine.
I want that when i click on "section start" label it should autofocus on selectbox(New Page).

```css
    .wrap 
    {
     width: 393px;
     height: 545px;
     border: 1px solid #0855DD;
     border-top: 1px solid #0734DA;
     border-color: #004DE3 #00138C #00138C #0855DD;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0855DD inset,0 0 1px 3px #0831D9 inset,0 0 0 2px #166AEE inset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0855DD inset,0 0 1px 3px #0831D9 inset,0 0 0 2px #166AEE inset;
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0855DD inset,0 0 1px 3px #0831D9 inset,0 0 0 2px #166AEE inset;
     margin: 20px;
    }
    .outline, .wrap
    {
     -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
     border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    }
    .outline
    {
     height: 26px;
     width: 391px;
     border-bottom: none;
     background: #3d95ff;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3d95ff), color-stop(4%,#2b90ff), color-stop(8%,#0372ff), color-stop(12%,#0365f1), color-stop(16%,#005cec), color-stop(20%,#0058e6), color-stop(28%,#0054e3), color-stop(48%,#0055e5), color-stop(60%,#0058ee), color-stop(68%,#0160f5), color-stop(72%,#0060f9), color-stop(76%,#0164f9), color-stop(80%,#026afe), color-stop(88%,#036eff), color-stop(96%,#0368fa), color-stop(100%,#0060f9));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3d95ff 0%,#2b90ff 4%,#0372ff 8%,#0365f1 12%,#005cec 16%,#0058e6 20%,#0054e3 28%,#0055e5 48%,#0058ee 60%,#0160f5 68%,#0060f9 72%,#0164f9 76%,#026afe 80%,#036eff 88%,#0368fa 96%,#0060f9 100%);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3d95ff 0%, #2b90ff 4%, #0372ff 8%, #0365f1 12%, #005cec 16%, #0058e6 20%, #0054e3 28%, #0055e5 48%, #0058ee 60%, #0160f5 68%, #0060f9 72%, #0164f9 76%, #026afe 80%, #036eff 88%, #0368fa 96%, #0060f9 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3d95ff 0%,#2b90ff 4%,#0372ff 8%,#0365f1 12%,#005cec 16%,#0058e6 20%,#0054e3 28%,#0055e5 48%,#0058ee 60%,#0160f5 68%,#0060f9 72%,#0164f9 76%,#026afe 80%,#036eff 88%,#0368fa 96%,#0060f9 100%);
    }
    .outline, .container, .page_set_form, .out_heading
    {
     margin: auto;
    }
    .out_heading 
    {
     line-height: 27px;
     height: 14px;
     width: 385px;
     margin: 3px;
    }
    .container, .preview
    {
     width: 357px;
    }
    .container
     {
     height: 427px;
     padding: 9px;
     padding-left: 7px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(
     linear,
     left top,
     left bottom,
     color-stop(0, #FCFCFE),
     color-stop(1, #F4F3EE),
     color-stop(1, #FBFBFD),
     color-stop(1, #FBFBFC),
     color-stop(1, #FBFAFB),
     color-stop(1, #FAFBFB),
     color-stop(1, #FAFAFA),
     color-stop(1, #F9FAF9),
     color-stop(1, #F9F8F9),
     color-stop(1, #F9F9F8),
     color-stop(1, #F8F8F7),
     color-stop(1, #F8F7F5),
     color-stop(1, #F7F6F4),
     color-stop(1, #F6F5F2),
     color-stop(1, #F5F5F1),
     color-stop(1, #F5F4EF),
     color-stop(1, #F5F3F0),
     color-stop(1, #F4F3EF)
     );
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCFCFE 0%, #F4F3EE 100%, #FBFBFD 100%, #FBFBFC 100%, #FBFAFB 100%, #FAFBFB 100%, #FAFAFA 100%, #F9FAF9 100%, #F9F8F9 100%, #F9F9F8 100%, #F8F8F7 100%, #F8F7F5 100%, #F7F6F4 100%, #F6F5F2 100%, #F5F5F1 100%, #F5F4EF 100%, #F5F3F0 100%, #F4F3EF 100%);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FCFCFE 0%, #F4F3EE 100%, #FBFBFD 100%, #FBFBFC 100%, #FBFAFB 100%, #FAFBFB 100%, #FAFAFA 100%, #F9FAF9 100%, #F9F8F9 100%, #F9F9F8 100%, #F8F8F7 100%, #F8F7F5 100%, #F7F6F4 100%, #F6F5F2 100%, #F5F5F1 100%, #F5F4EF 100%, #F5F3F0 100%, #F4F3EF 100%);
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCFCFE 0%, #F4F3EE 100%, #FBFBFD 100%, #FBFBFC 100%, #FBFAFB 100%, #FAFBFB 100%, #FAFAFA 100%, #F9FAF9 100%, #F9F8F9 100%, #F9F9F8 100%, #F8F8F7 100%, #F8F7F5 100%, #F7F6F4 100%, #F6F5F2 100%, #F5F5F1 100%, #F5F4EF 100%, #F5F3F0 100%, #F4F3EF 100%);
    }
    .heading
    {
     width: 300px;
     color: #ffffff;
     font: 600 13px arial;
    }
    .right_img
    {
     margin-right: 0;
     width: 12%;
    }
    .help_img, .cross_img
    {
     width: 21px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
     -moz-border-radius: 1px;
     border-radius: 1px;
    }
    .help_img 
    {
     background: url("image/help2.png") no-repeat;
    }
    .cross_img 
    {
     background: url("image/cross2.png") no-repeat;
    }
    .page_set_form 
    {
     height: 503px;
     width: 379px;
     padding: 6px 5px;
     background-color: #ECE9D8;
     border-top: 1px solid #3879D9;
    }
    .block_one
     {
     width: 196px;
     right: 37px;
     bottom: 10px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .tab 
    {
     width: 203px;
    }
    .tab_new, .tab_form_file, .tab_layout, .container
    {
     border: 1px solid #919B9C;
    }
    .tab_new, .tab_form_file, .tab_layout
    {
     -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
    .tab_new
    {
     width: 50px;
    }
    .tab_form_file
    {
     width: 51px;
    }
    .right_img, .help_img, .cross_img, .sup_endnote, .div_block
    {
     height: 21px;
    }
    .tab_new, .tab_form_file
    {
     height: 18px;
     background: #e3e9ec;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e3e9ec), color-stop(7%,#fdfdfc), color-stop(27%,#f6f6f4), color-stop(100%,#f0f0eb));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e3e9ec 0%,#fdfdfc 7%,#f6f6f4 27%,#f0f0eb 100%);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e3e9ec 0%, #fdfdfc 7%, #f6f6f4 27%, #f0f0eb 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e3e9ec 0%,#fdfdfc 7%,#f6f6f4 27%,#f0f0eb 100%);
    }
    .tab_layout 
    {
     width: 53px;
     padding-right: 3px;
     line-height: 23px;
     border-top: 1px solid #E68B2C;
     border-bottom-width: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #FFC83C inset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #FFC83C inset;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #FFC83C inset;
     border-left-width: 0;
     bottom: 2px;
     background-color: #FCFCFE;
    } 
    .tab_new, .tab_form_file, .tab_layout, .section, .type_checkbox:checked:after
    {
     display: block;
    }
    .one_label, .supress_label, .pos, .new_page_select, .div_block
    {
     position: relative;
    }
    .one_label, .firstpage_label, .supress_label
    {
     right: 3px;
    }
    .side_line, .section_label, .vertical_align, .line, .border
    {
     height: 0;
    }
    .side_line
    {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0BF;
     bottom: 6px;
     left: 3px;
    }
    .section_hr 
    {
     width: 319px;
    }
    .page, .section
    {
     padding-top: 8px;
    }
    .section
     {
     height: 49px;
    }
    .section_start 
    {
     display: inline-block;
    }
    .section_start, .vertical_align 
    {
     line-height: 22px;
    }
    .section, .section_start, .sup_endnote, .section_select
    {
     width: 219px;
    }
    .checkbox_one, .checkbox_two, .section_start
    {
     height: 19px;
    }
    .sup_endnote 
    {
     color: #ACA899;
    }
    .new_page_select 
    {
     border: 1px solid;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 11px;
    }
    .font_size, .page_set_form, .button_one
    {
     font: 11px arial;
    }
    .apply, .edge, .selectbox_two, .selectbox_one, .tab  
    {
     display: inline-flex;
    }
    .new_page_select, .header_select, .footer_select, .align_selectbox, .apply_select
    {
     border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    .new_page_select, .align_selectbox, .apply_select
    {
     background: url("image/arrow1.png") no-repeat right #ffffff;
    }
    .odd_even_checkbox, .first_page_checkbox
    {
     border: 1px solid #1C5180;
     background: #dcdcd7; 
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#dcdcd7), color-stop(20%,#dcdcd7), color-stop(54%,#f2f2f2), color-stop(100%,#f1f1ef));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #dcdcd7 0%,#dcdcd7 20%,#f2f2f2 54%,#f1f1ef 100%); 
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #dcdcd7 0%, #dcdcd7 20%, #f2f2f2 54%, #f1f1ef 100%); 
     background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #dcdcd7 0%,#dcdcd7 20%,#f2f2f2 54%,#f1f1ef 100%);
    }
    .odd_even_checkbox, .first_page_checkbox, .hidden_checkbox , .type_checkbox:checked:after
    {
     height: 13px;
     width: 13px;
    }
    .odd_even_checkbox, .first_page_checkbox, .hidden_checkbox, .font_size
    {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    .type_checkbox:checked:after 
    {
     background: url(image/checked.png) no-repeat 0 2px;
     border: none;
     content: '';
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hidden_checkbox 
    {
     border: 1px solid #ACA899;
    }
    .headers
    {
     color: #0046D5;
    }
    .hnf_hr 
    {
     width: 255px;
    }
    .head_and_foot 
    {
     height: 91px;
     width: 229px;
     padding-top: 6px;
    }
    .head_and_foot, .section
    {
     padding-left: 6px;
    }
    .cancel_button, .head_three, .help_img
    {
     margin-left: 2px;
    }
    .side_line, .float_right, .header_select, .footer_select, .page_select
    {
     float: right;
    }
    .blue_label, .page_set_form, .blue_label_two
    {
     line-height: 15px;
    }
    .blue_label.pr
    {
     line-height: 16px;
    }
    .blue_label, .blue_label_two
    {
     height: 12px;
    }
    .blue_label
    {
     width: 42px;
    }
    .blue_label_two
    {
     width: 103px;
     white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .prev_hr2.prev_hr, .one_label, .firstpage_label, .supress_label
    {
     bottom: 5px;
    }
    .checkbox_one, .checkbox_two
    {
     width: 210px;
    }
    .left_button, .edge_label, .heading, .help_img, .section_label 
    {
     float: left;
    }
    .edge_label
    {
     height: 50px;
     width: 100px;
     line-height: 45px;
     padding: 0;
     margin-left: 3px;
    }
    .tab, .edge_right
    {
     line-height: 20px;
    }
    .edge_right
    {
     height: 55px;
     width: 130px;
    }
    .tab, .selectbox_one
    {
     padding-top: 2px;
    }
    .selectbox_one
    {
     width: 123px;
    }
    .header_label  
    {
     width: 47px;
    }
    .head_three
    {
     width: 61%;
    }
    .selectbox_two, .app_label
    {
     width: 122px;
    }
    .footer_label
    {
     width: 46px;
    }
    .foot_select
    {
     width: 63%;
    }
    .header_select, .footer_select
    {
     height: 16px;
     width: 68px;
     background: url("image/drop.png") no-repeat right #ffffff;
     margin-right: 2px;
     padding-left: 1px;
    }
    .section_start
    {
     padding-left: 3px;
    }
    .height_value, .button_one
    {
     height: 22px;
    }
    .selectbox_two, .section_select, .apply
    {
     height: 23px;
    }
    .selectbox_two, .outline
    {
     padding-top: 1px;
    }
    .header_select, .align_selectbox
     {
     margin-left: 8px;
    }
    .footer_select
     {
     margin-left: 11px;
    }
    .new_page_select
    {
     margin-right: 13px;
    }
    .edge
    {
     height: 54px;
     width: 222px;
    }
    .page_hr 
    {
     width: 330px;
    }
    .page
     { 
     height: 65px;
     width: 297px;
     padding-left: 8px;
    }
    .page_contain 
    {
     height: 25px;
     width: 217px;
    }
    .vertical_align 
    {
     width: 206px;
    }
    .page_select 
    {
     width: 126px;
    }
    .align_selectbox, .new_page_select, .apply_select
    {
     width: 119px;
    }
    .prev_hr
    {
     width: 316px;
    }
    .preview 
    {
     height: 148px;
     padding-top: 4px;
    }
    .new_page_select, .img_previous
    {
     margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .img_previous
    {
     height: 113px;
     width: 91px;
     background: url("image/preview1.png") no-repeat;
     border-left: 24px solid transparent;
    }
    .default_button, .container, .tab_form_file
    {
     margin-left: 1px;
    }
    .default_button, .edge_label
    {
     letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    }
    .right_button, .left_button
    {
     height: 24px;
    }
    .left_button
    {
     width: 72px;
    }
    .buttons
    {
     height: 32px;
     width: 377px;
    }
    .selectbox_two, .heading, .tab
    {
     height: 20px;
    }
    .apply_select
    {
     margin-left: 9px;
    }
    .line_button 
    {
     margin-left: 6px;
    }
    .line, .border, .line_button
    {
     width: 93px;
    }
    .line
    {
     width: 191px;
    }
    .border
    {
     width: 89px;
    }
    .select
    {
        width: 367px;
    }
    .apply
    {
     padding-top: 13px;
     width: 359px;
    }
    .app_label, .select, .line, .right_button
    {
     height: 30px;
    }
    .app_label, .heading
    {
     line-height: 24px;
    }
    .select 
    {
     margin-right: 11px;
    }
    .section_label, .select, .line
    {
     width: 120px;
    }
    .line 
    {
     margin-right: 3px;
    }
    .border 
    {
     height: 120px;
    }
    .default_button, .ok_button, .cancel_button, .border_button 
    {
     width: 74px;
    }
    .border_button 
    {
     margin-left: 7px;
    }
    .line_button, .border_button, .ok_button, .cancel_button, .default_button
    {
     background: #ffffff;
     border: 1px solid #003C74;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .right_button 
    {
     width: 161px;
    }
    .ok_button 
    {
     margin: 0 6px 0 3px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #CEE7FF inset,3px 0 0 -1px #bcd4f6 inset, 0 0px 0 2px #6982EE inset, 3px 0 0 0 #99B8EA inset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #CEE7FF inset,3px 0 0 -1px #bcd4f6 inset, 0 0px 0 2px #6982EE inset, 3px 0 0 0 #99B8EA inset;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #CEE7FF inset,3px 0 0 -1px #bcd4f6 inset, 0 0px 0 2px #6982EE inset, 3px 0 0 0 #99B8EA inset;
     outline: 1px dotted #000000;
     outline-offset: -4px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .default_button, .cancel_button, .ok_button
    {
     margin-top: 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
     -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     border-radius: 2px;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(26%,#f6f6f3), color-stop(84%,#f0f0ea), color-stop(89%,#ebebe5), color-stop(100%,#d6d0c5));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f3 26%,#f0f0ea 84%,#ebebe5 89%,#d6d0c5 100%);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f3 26%, #f0f0ea 84%, #ebebe5 89%, #d6d0c5 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f3 26%,#f0f0ea 84%,#ebebe5 89%,#d6d0c5 100%);
    }
    .line_button, .border_button
    {
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(15%,#f6f6f3), color-stop(84%,#f0f0ea), color-stop(89%,#ebebe5), color-stop(100%,#d6d0c5));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f3 15%,#f0f0ea 84%,#ebebe5 89%,#d6d0c5 100%);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f3 15%, #f0f0ea 84%, #ebebe5 89%, #d6d0c5 100%); 
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f3 15%,#f0f0ea 84%,#ebebe5 89%,#d6d0c5 100%);
    }
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder
     {
     color: #000000;
    }
    .new_page_select, .padding_left, .align_selectbox, .apply_select, .button_one
    {
     padding-left: 2px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
       
     <div class="outline">
  <div class="out_heading">
   <div class="heading">
    <label>Page Setup</label>
   </div>
   <div class="right_img height_value float_right">
    <div class="help_img">
    </div>
    <div class="cross_img float_right">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <form name="page_setup_form" id="page_setup_form" class="page_set_form">
  <div class="block_one div_block">
   <ul class="tab">
    <li class="tab_new" accesskey="c">Margins</li>
    <li class="tab_form_file" accesskey="b">
     <label class="form_file">Paper</label>
    </li>
    <li class="tab_layout div_block">Layout</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="blue_label">
    <label class="headers">Section</label>
   </div>
   <div class="section_hr pos side_line">
   </div>
   <div class="section">
    <div class="section_start">
     <div class="section_label">
      <label for="hello">Section sta<u>r</u>t:</label>
     </div>
     <div class="section_select float_right">
      <select name="select_start" id="hello" class="new_page_select height_value font_size float_right" accesskey="r">
       <option value="1" selected="selected">New page</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sup_endnote">
     <input type="checkbox" name="hidden_checkbox" id="hidden_checkbox" class="hidden_checkbox type_checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
     <label class="supress_label">Suppress endnotes</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="blue_label_two">
    <label class="headers">Headers and footers</label>
   </div>
   <div class="hnf_hr pos side_line">
   </div>
   <div class="head_and_foot">
    <div class="checkbox_one">
     <input type="checkbox" name="odd_even_checkbox" id="odd_even_checkbox" class="odd_even_checkbox type_checkbox" accesskey="o"/>
     <label class="one_label" for="odd_even_checkbox">Different <u>o</u>dd and even</label> 
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox_two">
     <input type="checkbox" name="first_page_checkbox" id="first_page_checkbox" class="first_page_checkbox type_checkbox" accesskey="p"/>
     <label class="firstpage_label pos" for="first_page_checkbox">Different first <u>p</u>age</label>
    </div>
    <div class="edge">
     <div class="edge_label">
      <label>From edge:</label>
     </div>
     <div class="edge_right float_right">
      <div class="selectbox_one height_value float_right">
       <div class="header_label height_value">
        <label for="header_select"><u>H</u>eader:</label>
       </div>
       <div class="head_three height_value">
        <input type="number" name="header_select" id="header_select" class="header_select padding_left font_size" placeholder="0.5&#34;" step="0.1" min="0" max="10" accesskey="h"/>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="selectbox_two height_value float_right">
       <div class="footer_label height_value">
        <label for="footer_select"><u>F</u>ooter:</label>
       </div>
       <div class="foot_select height_value">
        <input type="number" name="footer_select" id="footer_select" class="footer_select padding_left font_size" placeholder="0.5&quot;" step="0.1" min="0" max="10"  accesskey="f"/>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="blue_label">
    <label class="headers">Page</label>
   </div>
   <div class="page_hr pos side_line">
   </div>
   <div class="page">
    <div class="page_contain">
     <div class="vertical_align">
      <label for="align_selectbox"><u>V</u>ertical alignment:</label>
     </div>
     <div class="page_select height_value">
      <select name="align_selectbox" id="align_selectbox" class="align_selectbox height_value font_size" accesskey="v">
       <option value="1" selected="selected">Top</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="blue_label pr">
    <label class="headers">Preview</label>
   </div>
   <div class="prev_hr2 prev_hr pos side_line">
   </div>
   <div class="preview float_right">
    <div class="img_previous">
    </div>
    <div class="apply">
     <div class="app_label">
      <label for="apply_selectbox">Appl<u>y</u> to:</label>
     </div>
     <div class="select">
      <select name="apply_selectbox" id="apply_selectbox" class="apply_select height_value font_size" accesskey="y">
       <option value="1" selected="selected">This point forward</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="line">
      <button type="button" name="line_no_btn" id="line_no_btn" class="line_button button_one" accesskey="n">Line <u>N</u>umbers...</button>
     </div>
     <div class="border height_value">
      <button type="button" name="border_btn" id="border_btn" class="border_button button_one" accesskey="b"><u>B</u>orders...</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
   <div class="left_button">
    <button type="button" name="default_button" id="default_button" class="default_button button_one" accesskey="d"><u>D</u>efault...</button>
   </div>
   <div class="right_button float_right">
    <input type="button" name="ok_button" id="ok_button" class="ok_button button_one" value="OK" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <input type="button" name="cancel_button" id="cancel_button" class="cancel_button button_one float_right" value="Cancel"/>
   </div>
  </div>
      </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't see what's not working. What do you mean ...

Comment: when i press on "section start" it automatically autofocus on select box(New page) for eg:- click on vertical alignment label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS rule
div.section_select width is set to 219 px covering the label text , so make its width auto

```
.section_select {
width:auto;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/LoLzcwc3/2/)
hope this works..

Comment: It works thanks and please explain the issue.If i decrease the width then the structure disturbs.

Comment: width is the issue, you are making two block level elements (div's) sit side by side , instead make them inline-block elements by using display property. you are making the parent and child element have the same width